# Why does the notifications are sending

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, workflow

I have the next workflow created in SharePoint Designer:

[image]

The goal is that when the due date is near (15 days), the workflow has to send a notification email. But at the moment I upload a file, the notification is sent. Why is this happening?

Thanks a lot for your help in this.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, your workflow will always send emails unless the State equals "No expiration date".

So, if you don't want to send emails, you probably want to remove the "send mail" activity inside the else block.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Denis!
I delete that instruction from the block "else" and the notifications stopped.
I really appreciate it.

Comment: @DamianCastañeda, can you please accept the answer? :)